# CMS recommendations for HTML CSS competent noob developer

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

so after a long break from it, I've decided to pick up web development again, and I'm having just as much trouble as ever, trying to pull apart and customise these CMSs. I'm getting a bit frustrated with it.

I'm pretty good with HTML and CSS, and can happily build websites that aren't linked to a Content Managment System (HTML, CSS, Javascript), but the complexity of a CMS seems to be too much for me to work with and understand.

I was hoping someone could recommend a dead simple framework for me to work with. Something that's really simple to understand how it works. I like the idea of a Flat File CMS, So far I've looked at Stacey, Grav and Kirby. I'm told these are simple to work with, but I'm still struggling to customise, and make the templates my own.

Ideally, what I'm looking for would be a cms where I could build the site in HTML and CSS and tack-on variables for things like image grids and menus into the HTML. Anyone heard of anything like this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-hosted Wordpress would be my recommendation.  As a 10+ year full-time web developer, I've used many CMSs and this one is always my go-to solution these days.  I seem to be constantly migrating clients away from other outdated platforms to Wordpress. Or you can use Wordpress.com if you don't want to go the self-hosted route.

If you work well with HTML and CSS you can make any style or markup changes you require.  If you haven't used PHP before, you'll have plenty of time to get familiar with it.  Once you are comfortable with some basic PHP, you can begin adding whatever functionality you want to your site via a plugin or by placing custom functions in the functions.php file of your theme.

If you haven't built anything with Wordpress yet, or if you aren't comfortable installing it on your webhost manually, you can use a webhost that has Fantastico to auto-install Wordpress for you.

There are tons of mobile-responsive themes out there that you can use as a starting point for your site, many of which are free.  It is recommended to use a child-theme for making your customizations.  This will prevent a theme update from erasing your changes.  If you are going to use a lot of javascript files it is also recommended to register and enqueue them inside the functions.php file.

It may take some time to familiarize yourself with Wordpress, but it should be well worth it.

For more info on all things related to Wordpress, check out the codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/

There is also a new Wordpress Code Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/

And if you run into any specific issues, first search here on Stack Overflow for the answer–it will usually be here already. If you can't find anything on your specific issue, create a new post with the details and someone will usually be happy to assist you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I've messed around with Wordpress a bit, and the biggest problem I see with it, is the admin interface seems really unintuitive. Do you know of a way to customise this at all?

Comment: There are admin themes you can get if you don't like the look of the admin area.  I feel that compared to most CMSs the administration area is way more intuitive, but that is just my opinion.

Plugins can add more functionality to the admin area.  But the main things to understand are that the news articles go under "Posts" and individual pages go under "Pages."  The theme can be edited under "Appearance -> Editor" but you should probably work off of a local copy to make your changes.

If you prefer the admin area of other CMSs, please use what works best for you. Cheers.

Comment: Cheers, I'll look into that.

Comment: I've been doing Wordpress tutorials, and I've been pleasantly surprised. It's surprisingly simple to create themes from scratch, and the workflow is way, way nicer (more logical) than I had imagined. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder) CMS. It was prettier now on version 9, with more feature and flexibility.
You can download the complete source of odoo, and develop it develop it in local before deploy on your server.

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting, I'll take a closer look...